# Howo to generate a seperate file for masm assembly using cl Preprocess

Tags: c++, cl

I have a c/c++ .h file (okay .h implies c).

I have a conditional #ifdef block. In one case, the block prepares statements for input into masm. The second code block is for use in the C/C++ build.

The cl command I am playing around with is as follows.

`cl /D=ASM_PREPROCESS /P /EP BootDefs.h /Fi:BootDefs.i`

The code block in the .h file looks like:

```
#ifdef ASM_PREPROCESS

MASM statements here

#else

C/C++ statements here.

#endif
```

However, when I run the cl command, all I am getting are empty lines in the .i file. Clearly there is something I am doing wrong. I just wonder whether any fellow engineers see the problem. I think it is related to stdout, but for the life of me, I cannot see the correct flag to apply.

The toolset I am using is Visual Studio 2019 and latest SDK.

Answer (score -1):

I have fixed the problem.

It was related to the /D=ASM_PREPROCESS. I think this is a bug, however changing to /DASMPREPROCESS fixed the issue.

Doh!